# Bash script to replace invalid Windows characters in file names

Tags: bash, perl, rename

I have a list of files in Ubuntu 18.04 and most of them are containing invalid chars for Windows perspective.

I mean that I have file name like: `Lesson 1 : Piano.mp4`, The `:` is invalid for Windows and cannot download it.

I tried with

```
rename 's/:/\-/g' *
```

but it does not replace anything

How to solve it ? I'm trying in first phase to replace `:` with `-`

Comment: Do you have perl rename or the one util-linux provides? With latter, `rename - : *` would do the job.

Comment: @oguzismail seems to be perl rename: Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E *perlexpr*]*|*perlexpr*
    [ *files* ]

Comment: The characters \/:"*?<>| are not valid in Windows filenames. These characters are used to delimit drives and folders, to quote paths, or to specify wildcards and redirection on the command line.

Comment: as per this url https://serverfault.com/questions/348482/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames you can use  `mv 'file' $(echo 'file' | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')` or  `f='file'; mv 'file' ${f//[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_}`  commands. Also you can check  (detox) https://linux.die.net/man/1/detox utility

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file name is stored in a variable `fn`,

```
fn='Lesson 1 : Piano.mp4'
```

you can do a

```
mv -v "$fn" "${fn/:/-}"
```

BTW, there are a few more characters beside the colon, which are not allowed in Windows, and certain filenames are completely forbidden too. This is explained here: https://kizu514.com/blog/forbidden-file-names-on-windows-10/

Comment: I have to bulk job, not on only file

Comment: Then do it in a loop for every file.

Comment: as per https://serverfault.com/questions/348482/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames  you can try `find /path/to/files -type f -print0 | \
perl -n0e '$new = $_; if($new =~ s/[^[:ascii:]]/_/g) {
  print("Renaming $_ to $new\n"); rename($_, $new);
}'` for bulk rename job

Comment: @amitbhosale : If you go so far to do the renaming in Perl (which makes sense, since the OP tagged the question with _perl_ too), I would also use the Fille::Find from Perl to loop over the files. No need to create a separate Perl process each file.

Comment: @user1934428 , very true,  above code is resource consuming. (mentioned because command line execution is easy for user).